# Changes to capitalization in .bib file not reflected in output

Tags: bibtex, miktex, texstudio

In reviewing my document I found errors in capitalization of some acronyms in titles of references (dc or Dc instead of DC, etc). When I corrected the .bib file, changes were not reflected in the output. If I make more substantive changes (adding/removing words) they are reflected.

I am using BibTeX, MikTeX, and TeXstudio with:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

to set up the document class.

And this call for building the bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref}
```

Here's an example reference entry in `ref.bib`:

```
@article{patterson2012:green_building,
  title={DC, come home: DC microgrids and the birth of the `enernet'},
  author={Patterson, Brian T},
  journal={IEEE Power and Energy Magazine},
  volume={10},
  number={6},
  pages={60--69},
  year={2012},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

And the output:

[image]

As others with similar problems attempted, I deleted all temp files (aux, bbl, blg, log, and gz) then compiled twice - but this didn't work.

Comment: Did you try writing `{DC}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either enclose the full title in double curly braces:

```
title={{DC, come home: DC microgrids and the birth of the `enernet'}},
```

or put them around the individual letters you want to have capitalised:

```
title={{DC}, come home: {DC} microgrids and the birth of the `enernet'},
```